# ASP.NET strange server error on file download

Tags: asp.net

I've got very strange error when trying download zip file, generated on the fly.
On some client computers everything is OK, file downlading perfect, on others there is server exception (I am trying to test using different browsers):

Message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
StackTrace:
в ASP.development_detail_aspx.__RenderContent1(HtmlT­extWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) в System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlT­extWriter writer, ICollection children) в System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlT­extWriter writer, ICollection children) в System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren­(HtmlTextWriter writer) в System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTex­tWriter output) в System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(­HtmlTextWriter writer) в System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlT­extWriter writer, ICollection children) в System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlT­extWriter writer, ICollection children) в System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) в System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

My code in asp:ImageButton OnClick event. Server is IIS 7.5:

...

```
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(output))
    {
        s.SetLevel(5); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];


        foreach (var file in devFiles)
        {
            if (file.PhisicalName != "")
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.RealName);
                s.PutNextEntry(entry);
                using (FileStream streamer = File.OpenRead(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file.PhisicalName)))
                {
                    int sourceBytes;
                    do
                    {
                        sourceBytes = streamer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        s.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                    }
                    while (sourceBytes > 0);
                } 
            }
        }

    s.Finish();    
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=doc.zip");
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", output.Length.ToString());
    response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
    response.End();
    output.Close();
    s.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where is output declared and initialised?

Comment: Whats the size of the zip file? I have seen something similar happen once due to there not being enough memory on the server for the w3wp process to load the attached file

Comment: I've updated the code. The size of the file is about 10M. But it works on some clients.. on some not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, find the answer. It was very simple/stupid. 
Above in the code there was a check if user was logged in. If not there was nothing to render.
For people who was logged in admin interface everithing was OK, but others got Render exception. 
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I make an assume here and I am not 100% sure.

The **response.End() is throw an exception**, and after that probably the rest page is go randomly ! because you (and I) do not know where the exception is jump. So the close file command is bypassed !.

I suggest to remove the **End()**, and use the **Flush()**

Also I suggest to use the **using(){} for the file open close**, and maybe a **buffering read** of the file due to memory problems if the zip file is too big.

**Also with this code you have open files left**, so maybe the output in the next cycle is null because can not open the file...

Comment: @Automator then maybe is the size of the zip, you need to change the way you read it - and read it with a buffer part by part. In witch line you get the null exception ?

Comment: What is strange the same files on some computers downloaded ok, on others not, zip always the same.

Comment: @Automator Then maybe is cut by a firewall/antivirus ? and close the connection... Can you check this Response.IsClientConnected, in the buffering process just to check it out ?